# Want to create a String type array from file type array in java

Tags: java

I have a File type array which is converted one by one into String type now i want to make an array of all converted string. Don't know how to do this and stuck here.

```
 FTPFile[] files = client.list();
    for (FTPFile file : files) {
          System.out.println(file.getName());
    //How to make an array of file.getName
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not a good application of the enhanced for-loop which masks the iterator variable. Second, I'm not sure *which* `FTPFile` implementation you're using, but I'll offer this snippet, assuming your use of [Apache Commons `FTPFile`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html#getName%28%29).

```
String[] strings = new String[files.length];
for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    strings[i] = files[i].getName(); // or whatever method call your FTPFile has
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare an `Array` of `String` that will hold your file names, and change the `for` loop based on an index so you can assign each element of the fileNames array a value

```java
FTPFile[] files = client.list();
String[] fileNames = new String[files.length];
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(files[i].getName());
  //Just add the file name to the array of Strings
  fileNames[i] = files[i].getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 you could do something like this:

```
String[] strings = Arrays.stream(files)
        .map(FTPFile::getName)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

A little explanation:

- `Arrays.stream(files)` returns a `Stream` about the elements of the files `Array`
- `.map(FTPFile::getName)` is a mapping from type `FTPFile` to type `String` (the return type of `getName` and your desired target type). It is done by a method reference (the double colon `::`) as a short form for the lambda expression: `element -> element.getName()`
- `.toArray(String[]::new);` creates a new String[] and stores all elements of the stream in it, again a method reference is used (long form would have been: `size -> new String[size]`

See [JavaDoc - Stream (Java Platform SE8)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for further information on Streams

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
      String[] ss = Arrays.stream(files).
              map(f -> f.getName()).
              toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score -1):

Something as below

```
FTPFile[] files = client.list();
int size = files.length;
int i =0;
String a []=new String[size];

    for (FTPFile file : files) {
          System.out.println(file.getName());

           a[i] = file.getName();
           i++;
 }
```

Comment: A `String[]` does not have a method `add()`. This is an array, not a `List<String>`.

Comment: There's still a problem. Where is `i` declared, and why would you allow it to leak outside loop scope?

Comment: @hexafraction Thanx, but i need more understanding on the leak part, might be useful to others as well.

Comment: In this code, after the loop ends, `i` can still be accessed. When you declare `i` in `for(int i = 0; ...)`, then it is only on the stack for the time while the loop itself is executing, and you do not risk accidentally getting confused and using it after the loop ends.

Comment: i works but when using a[] somewhere else out of the loop its giving null except the first one on 0th postition